# How to achieve a mouseover effect, possibly jquery

Tags: jquery

I wanted to know how the expansion effect has been achieved on this page http://jan.dyrda.org/html/udemy_coupons.html?

I believe Jquery has been used. If someone can point me to a resource which has information on how to achieve the same effect I would be grateful.

Comment: What expansion effect?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific.

I'm interested in the effect that is achieved when you mouseover a coupon and it expands to show the details of the udemy coupon.

Is it possible to achieve this via only CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the expanding boxes toward the bottom of the page, that can be achieved using the jQuery slideDown() effect.
There is a very basic example at w3Schools

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("p").slideUp();
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("p").slideDown();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button class="btn1">Slide up</button>
<button class="btn2">Slide down</button>

</body>
</html>
```

[w3schools jQuery slideDown()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidedown.asp)

You would just need to replace the button click events with mouse over and mouse out events for the thumbnail image

Comment: Thanks @smitty1.

It is advisable to use JS or use CSS to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user3186051 While you can achieve a similar effect with CSS, if you want to use easing effects similar to those on the website you referenced, you would likely need to use jQuery or some other JavaScript based solution.  There may be some way to achieve an easing effect purely with CSS (if there is, I have never came across one), but it would probably be a much more complicated solution than using jQuery.  CSS has continued to develop and branch out from mere styling, so it may be more easily achievable than it was a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

by looking at the source code of that page I've found that there are elements tagged as roundabouts ... after some quick googling I think this one might be good for your needs http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/

Comment: thank you @cristi_b.

The answer really helps as not only did you guide me in the right direction but also you have shared how you did your research which will help me in future.

Comment: no problem... you're welcome, there are many approaches to solving a certain problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the thumbnails you can do that using CSS. To create that effect you will need to edit the transition, display, z-index, overflow and height or you can use a jquery plugin to achive that.

You can find out more about transitions in [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) page:

Comment: this is what I exactly wanted though I did not specify earlier that I would prefer a CSS solution.

Thanks.